# Cannot run simple Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the script in my javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('link').click(function () {

    $('box').fadeOut();
   });
});
```

This is the html:

```
  <div role="main" id="box">  </div>



<a id="link" href="#">ClickMe</a>
```

with these paths in the footer of my html page:

```
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>


 <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Does the ".fadeOut" function not exist in Jquery 1.9.1??
Am I missing something in my javascript file at the top of the page?
Some kind of other document ready function??
This is so absurd it's frustrating.

Comment: $('#link') and $('#box'). Need to specify if it's an id or a class

Comment: Try adding the reference to your own script after the jquery script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selectors are wrong. Try

```
$('#link').click(function () {
    $('#box').fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the

`<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

above

`<script src="js/script.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

```
$("#box")...
$("#link")...
```

You are missing `#`s in your code.

---

```
$("box")...
```

This is referring to the `<box>` tag, which doesn't exist.

---

Also include jQuery and other libraries before including your own scripts. Make sure you include jQuery inside `<head>`.

---

### Examples

```
$("a")  //<a> tag
$("#a") //element with ID "a"
$(".a") //elements with class name "a"
```

Comment: + `#link` + order of script insertions.

Comment: @Christoph - Thanks. Updated. (I was still typing the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are not correctly used. try it this way

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#link').click(function () {
     $('#box').fadeOut();
   });
});
```

you where missing the # in your selectors. Remember the Jquery function uses css standard selectors to access DOM elements.